# Adding interest groups when using SL Mailchimp Subscribe

Tags: mailchimp

I know there are alternatives but does anyone know how to set up the interest groups field when using SL Mailchimp Subscribe?

I've currently got a checkbox field containing the different Interest groups set up on the Mailchimp Mailing list but I'm unsure what values to use for each checkbox.

There is nothing in the documentation about this feature and an old video I found just shows the use of a dropdown field but with no indication of how that is actually configured.

Answer (score 0):

You just use the names of the Interest Groups as the checkbox values! Duh!
Easy when you don't overthink things.

Mailchimp accepts a comma delimited string of the group names. So if you use checkboxes it will only ever set one interest group. To set multiple groups you need to send the content from a plain text input.